# algorithms that destruct and copy_construct

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, stl, object-lifetime

I am currently building my own toy `vector` for fun, and I was wondering if there is something like the following in the current or next standard or in Boost?

```
template<class T>
void destruct(T* begin, T* end)
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        begin -> ~T();
        ++begin;
    }
}

template<class T>
T* copy_construct(T* begin, T* end, T* dst)
{
    while (begin != end)
    {
        new(dst) T(*begin);
        ++begin;
        ++dst;
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector`, if I'm not mistaken, applies its allocator's construct and destruct functions on individual items, so you could also use binders (like `std::tr1::bind`) to let `std::transform` and/or `std::for_each` do those.

But for the copying loop, there also appears to be [std::uninitialized_copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/uninitialized_copy/).

Comment: Ah, `uninitialized_copy` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Vector elements are destructed in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

The STL relies on [allocators](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Allocators.html) (passed as a default template parameter in STL containers) which have methods `construct` and `destroy` and others like `uninitialized_fill`, but not all of them operate on ranges.  The allocator, not the container, are responsible for providing these functions.  If you want to write your own vector class like the STL, you'll also need to reinvent allocators.